# Convert string to Color

Tags: c#, reflection, colors

I'm setting fields data via reflection. And I have a problem to convert string to Color, 
`Convert.ChangeType(stringValue,typeof(Color))` throws Exception. How can i convert to Color in this situation

```
        PropertyInfo[] propertis = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties();
        foreach (var attribute in element.Attributes())
        {
            var property = propertis.Where(x => x.Name == attribute.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            if (property != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(someVariable, Convert.ChangeType(attribute.Value,property.PropertyType), null);
            }
        }
```

P.S Color value is not allways a named Color, so Color.FromName doesnt work

Comment: It's not a named color, and you want to convert it to a `Color` how exactly?

Comment: without examples of what values the string can contain this cannot be answered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Color** struct has the **TypeConverter** attribute on it, so you can do something like this

```
var converter=TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property.PropertyType);
object convertedValue=converter.ConvertTo(attribute.Value, property.PropertyType);
property.SetValue(someVariable, convertedValue, null);
```

There's also the more useful (in your case) **ConvertFromString** method:

```
var converter=TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(property.PropertyType);
object convertedValue=converter.ConvertFromString(attribute.Value);
property.SetValue(someVariable, convertedValue, null);
```

A quick look at the class in Reflector suggests that it will parse the colors by name or by their hex value, which is what you're looking for :-)

The **System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter** framework is a lot more flexible that the **Convert** class

Answer (score 1):

Based on the PS note, I don't think you are going to be able to handle this.  The values have to be consistent, if it is a named color you can use `Color.FromName`, if it is a hex value you can use `Color.FromArgb`

If it isn't consistent, you are going to need to find a way to parse, determine the conversion, then complete it.